# mongoid-tags-arent-hard not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I am trying to use "mongoid-tags-arent-hard" Gem to add tag function to my Post/comment application using rails 4.2 and mongoid 4.

Gem is setup as per the documentation however, Post is getting saved without tags. In post document tag field is empty.

Following is the view/model/controller:

Please let me know if I am making any mistake.

```
View
    _form.html.erb
        <p>
          <%= f.label :tags %><br />
          <%= text_field_tag 'post[tags]' %>
        </p>
```

---

```
class Post

  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include Mongoid::TagsArentHard

  taggable_with :tags

  field :title, type: String
  slug :title

  field :description, type: String
  field :starred, type: Boolean

  validates :title, :presence => true, :length => { :minimum => 20, :allow_blank => false }

  embeds_many :comments
  embeds_many :answers

  belongs_to :user

End
```

---

Part of Post controller:

```
def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    @post.user = current_user

def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :description, :tags)
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corrected the view as shown below. Everything works fine now.

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :tags %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :tags %>
</div>
```